# Let $z_1,z_2$ be complex numbers with $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$. Prove that $|z_1 + 1| + |z_2 + 1| + |z_1z_2 + 1| \geq 2$

Tags: complex-numbers, problem-solving, triangle-inequality

> Let $z_1,z_2$ be complex numbers with $|z_1|=|z_2|=1$. Prove that :-
> $$|z_1 + 1| + |z_2 + 1| + |z_1z_2 + 1| \geq 2$$

**What I Tried**:- From Triangle Inequality, we have :-

$$|z_1 + 1| + |z_2 + 1| + |z_1z_2 + 1| \geq |(1 + z_1)(1 + z_2) + 2|$$

From here, no other specific ideas came to my mind. I still did not use the fact, $|z_1| = |z_2| = 1$, so from Triangle Inequality again, we get :-

$$|z_1 + 1| + |z_2 + 1| \leq 4$$

The $2$ equations seem nicely similar, but I wasn't able to connect them nicely.

Can someone help me? Thank You.

Algebraic Solutions will be preferred over Geometric Solutions.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1051372/42969.

Comment: @MartinR thank you, it can be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_1=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$ and $z_2=\cos\beta+i\sin\beta$.

Thus, we need to probe that $$|\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}|+|\cos\frac{\beta}{2}|+|\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}|\geq1,$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}+\cos\frac{\beta}{2}-\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}\geq1,$$ where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ or
$$\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}{4}\geq\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{4},$$ which is obvious.